# Node.js + Webpack + TypeScript: access to path of project with source files (not usage project)

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

Let's make clear once again: I don't need `process.cwd` in this question, I need
to access to absolute path of source project. E.g:

- Source code: `C:\Users\user1\projects\lib1\src\library.ts` (becomes to Node Module in the future)
- Project that uses Library: `C:\Users\user1\projects\someProject\src\someProject.ts`

So, I need to get the `C:\Users\user1\projects\lib1\src` inside `library.ts`.

I tried:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {

  // ...

  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],

  plugins: [
    new Webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __PROJECT_ROUTE_ABSOLUTE_PATH__: __dirname
    })
  ]
};
```

**project-types.d.ts**

```js
declare var __PROJECT_ROUTE_ABSOLUTE_PATH__: string;
```

If to try `console.log(__PROJECT_ROUTE_ABSOLUTE_PATH__)` in `library.ts`, below invalid JavaScript
will be produced:

```
console.log(C:\Users\user1\projects\lib1);
```

The path is correct, but quotations are missing. I don't know how to explain it. 
But anyway, how we can get right path?

There is also a strange phenomena: if to invoke `__dirname`, just `/` will be returned, so `path.resolve(__dirname, 'fileName') gives`C:\fileName `

[image]

Comment: Is this a node.js app ?

Comment: @Prasheel, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the node.js `path` module which is in built. 
The path module provides utilities for working with file and directory paths. It can be accessed using:

```
const path = require('path');
```

__filename is the file name of the current module. This is the resolved absolute path of the current module file. (ex:/home/user/some/dir/file.js)

__dirname is the directory name of the current module. (ex:/home/user/some/dir)

```
fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname + 'fileName'))
```

This will resolve to the path of the file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, in my PS, OS (Windows 10) and `library.ts`, `__dirname` returns just `/`. So, `path.resolve(__dirname + 'fileName')` returns just `C:\fileName`

Comment: Of course, no. Here is the console command that I use in parent project `C:\Users\me\Documents\PhpStorm\project>gulp development
`. Gulp runs library that also in development.

Comment: Can you add the gulp task to the question as well ??

Comment: Gulp task is just like `gulp.task('Development', gulp.series(markupPreprocessing));`.  `markupPreprocessing` is the function that imported from library. But error occurs in the dependency of `markupPreprocessing`, this dependency is also the part of library. I also added the image to question as evidence.

Comment: I found the first mistake. `__PROJECT_ROUTE_ABSOLUTE_PATH__: JSON.stringify(Path.normalize(__dirname))` will be work. Remain is to find out why `__dirname` returns `C` root.

Comment: This must be something related to execution context

Comment: I found the cause of this problem. As gratitude for your time, I improved your answer and now you can receive more reputation points.

Comment: @Gurebu Thanks.